# VUE2 component register in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Laravel(5.8) and VUE work very nice togheter, but my app.js is getting to big.

For example, i have the following app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

window.Vue.component('Comp1', require('./components/Comp1.vue').default);
window.Vue.component('Comp2', require('./components/Comp2.vue').default);
window.Vue.component('Comp3', require('./components/Comp3.vue').default);

window.mainApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

In the real case, I have around 30 components + third party, witch results in a 1.2mb JS for production.

So, I'm tring to break the app.js file in many 'area related' js, just split, so I wuld have someting like:

app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.mainApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

appMainComp.js:

```
window.Vue.component('Comp1', require('./components/Comp1.vue').default);
window.Vue.component('Comp2', require('./components/Comp2.vue').default);
```

appOtherComp.js:

```
window.Vue.component('Comp3', require('./components/Comp3.vue').default);
```

Now, the catch. Everthing that I register after the app.js "window.mainApp = new Vue({  el: '#app'});" do not register.

So, is there a way to register a component after my 'mainApp' is created? Something like

```
mainApp.addComponent('./components/Comp1.vue');
```

Or any other way to break the app.js in mutiple files?

Comment: If your app.js is getting bigger, maybe its time to consider loose coupling your backend from frontend, its a painful transition, but it pays well in long term. Just saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of splitting up components into groups (interesting idea btw). Could you do something like this?
[`Dynamic Imports in Vue.js`](https://vuedose.tips/tips/dynamic-imports-in-vue-js-for-better-performance/)

> Whenever it’s possible, I’d recommend to use dynamic imports to import components. They will be lazily loaded (by Webpack) when needed.

```js
//Instead of a usual import
import MyComponent from "~/components/MyComponent.js";

//do this
const MyComponent = () => import("~/components/MyComponent.js");
```

Comment: Amazing! Sadly the css of the components did not worked. Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: When you say the css of the component, are you importing the css or have it scoped?

Answer (score 0):

You could use stacks:

> Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child views.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#stacks

Parent view:

```
<head>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
    @stack('loadComponent')
    <script>
        @stack('addComponent')
    </script>            
</head>
```

Child view:

```
@push('loadComponent')
    <script src="..."></script>
@endpush

@push('addComponent')
    app.addComponent(...);
@endpush
```

Comment: that would work, thanks. BUT (always a but.. ^^" ) the components js are better to be imported as async ( <script async src="..."></script> ), so the user can interact with the page right away. In that case my components may or may not be initialized before the 'mainApp', so some components would not work sometimes. That is a good Blade solution, but I believe that I need a JS solution

Comment: I just c/p-ed the example with script tags straight from the laravel docs but you could use stacks anywhere you want, head, body or load stuff any way you want, require, import etc which can solve your async problem through dependencies.